# Crystal Date range to look into 2 fields in selection formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to bring all records that `if insull({exit.date )` then to bring records that are `{enter.date} <= {?start date} else if not isnull ({exit.date) then if {exit.date} > {?end date} but the {Enter Date} <= {?Start Date}` to pull that record `else if {Exit.date}<= {?End date} and the {enter.date}>=` to pull those records as well. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is all a bit jumbled here. So let's go through this:
you wan to bring in records that `(isNull({exit.date}) AND {enter.date} <= {?start date})`.
Next would be `<> isNull({exit.date}) AND {exit.date} > {?end date} AND {enter.date} > {?Start Date} AND {Exit.Date} > {?End Date}`. Not sure what the last condition is supposed to be since it's missing a part.
So at this point you're looking at something like `(isNull({exit.date}) AND {enter.date} <= {?start date}) AND ((<> isNull({exit.date})) AND ({exit.date} > {?end date}) AND ({enter.date} > {?Start Date}) AND ({Exit.Date} > {?End Date}))`
And of course all that goes into your Record Select.

Comment: That looks like its working but the only part is the {exit.date} > {?End date} to only bring if the {Enter.date} >= {?start date}

Comment: To be honest with you, I'm having a hard time getting all the conditions sorted out. But the way I did this is by reversing your conditions so that the report only brings over data that match the reversed condition. So that would make it ({exit.dat} > {?End Date}) AND ({Enter.Date} < {?start date}). Does that make sense?

Comment: if are doing reverse condition then yes, I will try it out and see if it brings me true data

Comment: I did the formula you suggested and got no data. I used isnull{exit.date} and {enter.date} <={?start date}// I think it should be >=/// and not isnull{exit.date} and {exit.date} > {?end date} and {start.date} <= {?start date} and {exit.date} <= {?end date}